# SQLite Delete from Table Slow on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row

**SQLite Version:** 3.7.4

**Android Version:** 3.2


I'm having trouble deleting from my table in a timely manor. Deleting around 200,000 records takes 15-30 mins. I've tried the following approach to no avail:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mySQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("delete from " + _tableName);
```

or

```
db.delete(_tableName, null, null);
```

or

```
db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + _tableName);
mySQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(db);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any other tables i.e. could you just delete the whole database? Also are there any foreign key constraints or the like in the database?

Comment: This is a 1 table database, so there are no foreign key constraints. The columns are: int Primary Key, int, int int, boolean, string, int, blob, blob. The blobs are serialized POJO lists, that aren't terribly complex. There are two indexes on the table as well. Nothing else I can think to mention other than that. While deleting the who database might be an option--I'd like to avoid it.